# ASP.NET MVC Controller waiting for Model before returning responses

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I need to creat an algorithm in which all calls to a specific action from the users will return the views at once even when the calls were not received at once . I have a static Model with a timer inside when the timer fires his event I want all the ActionResults of that action to be returned at once (From security reasons) . Is there any way I can block the Action Result From retuning until a model method/Event is being called? Should I use AJAX for such a thing ? and if so how would I go about returning a new view to the users with AJAX? (Only some users actually need to update the view I need to process the input they send in the model to know if the view needs to update)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to send messages to client in very specific time I don't think regular HTTP request are a way to go. You should probably be using WebSockets for that... that simply sounds just like a push message.